# I am confused with Unity c# inheritance

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have two simple scripts (`Parent` and `Child`) they are both on the same GameObject ("enemy"). enemy tries to find GameObject "Hero",
it manages to do so from three places, but from the forth place it just says "Null".

What am I doing wrong?

**Parent script:**

```
using UnityEngine;

public class Parent : MonoBehaviour
{
    private GameObject hero;

    protected GameObject FindHero()
    {
        hero = GameObject.Find("Hero");
        Debug.Log(hero); //Hero
        return hero;
    }
    private void Update()
    {
        Debug.Log(hero); //Null
    }
}
```

**Child script:**

```
using UnityEngine;

public class Child : Parent
{
    private void Update()
    {
        Debug.Log(FindHero()); //Hero
        Debug.Log(GameObject.Find("Hero")); //Hero
    }
}
```

Comment: @Llama but it is working without any errors (no error messages in unity console)

Comment: Sorry, I misread your code.

Comment: Is there any evidence that `FindHero()` is being called before `Update()` gets called? If you're not calling `FindHero()`, the field `hero` will never be set, and thus be `null` as `GameObject`'s default value is `null`.

Comment: @Llama Update() is a Unity method that is called every frame (approx. 60 times every second) that means that FindHero() is also being called every frame so the value "hero" is being set 60 times per second, but it is null when I am trying to access it from Update() in Parent script

Comment: I wold suggest you make `Update` in the `Parent` class `virtual`, and `override` it in the `Child` class. Then you can call `base.Update();` within your `Update()` method. I'm not sure how Unity handles method hiding as you're doing at the moment, to be honest.

Comment: You shouldn't apply parent-child inheritence with `MonoBehaviour`.  Any script you derive from `MonoBehaviour` should be considered `sealed`.  Unity is all about _composition_ not inheritence

Comment: @MickyD I have many types of enemies in my project and their behaviour is very similar, so I made a script for every enemy and extended it with other scripts with the help of inheritance

Comment: @Egor the danger is that that `Child.Update` **hides** `Parent.Update` and so an instance of `Child` only ever runs the `Update` defined in `Child` and the base method `Update` in `Parent` is not called.  Unity is not going to call `Update` on an object twice just to satisfy your inheritence design.   It is a code smell best avoided.  Also since you have 2 scripts applied to the object you are running with dual states hence why Child doesn't agree with Parent.  If you used composition you would not have add this issue

Comment: @MickyD I removed Update() from my parent class and also removed Parent class from my enemy, so now I have only one Update() in my Child class on my enemy.

Comment: Good, what you should do now is refactor `Child` to include `FindHero` and derive from `MonoBehaviour` since `Parent` no longer serves a purpose.  It's just to easy to hide methods otherwise

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you think is happening is that the `Child` script is accessing the *"hero"* `GameObject` on the `Parent` script - *which is not how inheritance works.*

The `Child` script is actually accessing the "hero" `GameObject` on **itself**. Meaning there isn't just one "hero" `GameObject`. There are two, one for the `Parent` script and one for the  `Child` script.

Think of the `Child` script as the `Parent` script plus extras.
Normally we don't put Both the `Child` and `Parent` on the same GameObject as it is redundant. You can still get both the `Child` and the `Parent` with `GetComponent<Parent>()`.

The reason your script is failing is the first `Parent` script never calls the `FindHero()` function. But the second `Parent (Child)` script does.

I would suggest you remove the `Parent` script from your gameobject and everything will work fine.

Comment: Thank you user15119845, It solved my problem with my project, also thank you all for trying to help me. I have multiple methods in my Parent class (there are two methods) that must be called on every enemy (I have multiple types of them)  I just put them in my child scripts and it works very well